# Can someone explain this part of the definition of a linear combination of column vectors to me?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is what I need explained: "The system **Ax**=**b** is consistent iff **b** can be expressed as a linear combination, where the coefficients of the linear combination are a solution of the system."

I thought a linear combination of column vectors was something like

$$x\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\end{pmatrix}$$

where you have to have coefficients AND variables and multiple matrices that are added together, but a system with a single solution would have just coefficients. And any solution would have just one column matrix, not a few added together.

Also, what is a situation that would cause **b** to NOT be able to be expressed as a linear combination? Would that just be when the system has no solution?

Am I reading too much into this, is it just saying that the system is consistent if it has a solution like 
$$t\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\end{pmatrix}\text{, or just }\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: The sum of column vectors **is** a single column vector.  $x\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x+3y\\2x+4y\end{pmatrix}$.  Technically the zero vector is a linear combination where each coefficient is zero (*or possibly some other if the vectors are linearly dependent*).  The extra f in "iff" implies it is the phrase "if and only if", so via contrapositive we have $b$ can not be expressed as a linear combination if and only if the system is inconsistent.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have a followup question -- what exactly does my book mean when it refers to Ax = b being consistent? What exactly is the meaning of consistent here? Is it the same thing as saying that the system of equations has at least one solution?

Comment: @dagny Yes, exactly

Answer (score 2):

$$x\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\2&4\end{pmatrix}}_A\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}}_{\bf x}$$

If we change this slightly to $$x\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{pmatrix}}_A\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}}_{\bf x}$$
then the result will never be $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$, for any values of $x,y$.